# Verify ADFS Token

Tags: node.js, authentication, asp.net-web-api, adfs3.0

I have a JWT retrieved using a usernamemixed endpoint in ADFS 3.0 and now I need to validate this token from a node.js application. How do I achieve this? I know how to validate this token from a WebAPI. I need to do pretty much the same thing in Node.js application. Can I rely just on validating signature of the token(Token Signing Certificate) in node.js, can it be spoofed?

Answer (score 0):

Token validation includes signature checks, but that's not all; you need to check for validation, audience, issuer, etc etc (see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/03/03/principles-of-token-validation/).
This is normally achieved by using a validation library that reads the issuer metadata and uses it to validate incoming tokens. If you'd be using ADFS "4.0" you could simply take the Azure AD web API node sample in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapi and point it to ADFS instead. ADFS "3.0" doesn't expose metadata using the openid connect discovery spec, used by that sample, hence the code won't work as-is. However it does provide the same info in its ws-federation metadata doc. If you implement the same scenario using the ASP.NET middleware and capture the network trace, you'll see how you can implement the same check yourself. If you can upgrade your ADFS instance to "4.0", that would be vastly preferable - way less custom code necessary.